# Using values of one csv file to populate another with pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, read.csv

I have two `csv` files. One is `query` file, the other is `key` file.

This is the `query` file:

```
Date       Copies Client Partner
07/10/2022 8      AAA    IM
07/10/2022 3      BBB    KZA
08/10/2022 10     AAA    KZA
09/10/2022 6      BBB    IM
```

It shows the copies made for each client and the partner working for it.

I need to add two columns `Client ID` and `Project ID`. Those details are in another `csv` file i.e. `key`.
I want pandas to look for the combination of Client + Partner and add in the right Project ID and Client ID in the next columns.

Note that the `Client ID` stays the same regardless of which partner is working on it, however the `Project ID` changes based on the combination of Client and Partner.

This is the `key` file:

```
Partner Client Project ID Client ID
IM      AAA    PRJ-01     CC002
IM      BBB    PRJ-09     CC008
IM      CCC    PRJ-11     CC006
KZA     AAA    PRJ-07     CC002
KZA     BBB    PRJ-04     CC008
MIA     AAA    PRJ-17     CC002
MIA     BBB    PRJ-14     CC008
```

I was thinking of using the `np.select` but the combination of clients and partners will take the inputs to several thousands:

```
 cond = [
        (df['Client'] == 'AAA'),
        (df['client'] == 'BBB'),
        ]
    
    choices = ['CC002','CC008']
    
    df['Client ID'] = np.select(cond, choices)

 cond2 = [
        (df['Client'] == 'AAA') & (df['Partner'] == 'IM'),
        (df['Client'] == 'AAA') & (df['Partner'] == 'KZA'),
        (df['Client'] == 'BBB') & (df['Partner'] == 'IM'),
        (df['Client'] == 'BBB') & (df['Partner'] == 'KZA'),
        ]
    
    choices2 = ['PRJ-01','PRJ-07','PRJ-09','PRJ-04']
    
    df['Project ID'] = np.select(cond2, choices2)
```

This will take me ages to put in all the date and hence I am looking for a solution that can read the `csv` files and automatically populate the date based on the combinations.

Little help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use `left` join in `merge`

Comment: It is not a simple merging operation. The combinations are haphazard

Comment: So then not understand logic of second select. Can you explain more?

Comment: For me working well `df = df.merge(df1, on=['Partner','Client'], how='left')`

Comment: The values of `key` are more than the `query` values. I have edited the question to show that